# How do I set up Prometheus on Docker in a way that makes sense from a network perspective?

Tags: docker, networking, prometheus

I want to setup a monitoring stack on docker with Prometheus and Grafana.
I have successfully deployed Prometheus, Grafana, node-exporter and cadvisor with docker-compose but I want to add other data sources to be scraped by Prometheus which are not provided by a docker container but by some other devices in my network which the docker host is part of.

So Prometheus has to reach the docker container node-exporter and cadvisor but also some external devices on my network.
Grafana has to reach Prometheus and has to be reached from my network.

I despair how an adequate network setup can look like, so that these requirements are met.

The problem with macvlans and ipvlans (as far as I am aware of): containers inside a macvlan cannot reach arbitrary hosts in the same IP namespace outside of the macvlan

The prolem with docker bridges: containers inside the bridge network cannot reach outside hosts because of the strict isolation

I considered adding "network_mode: host" to the Prometheus container but it still cannot reach other network devices (but I think it should)

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean bu "external devices on my network"
where are theses devices, and by your network do you mean host network or docker network?

Comment: I mean the host network that the Docker host belongs to and where there are devices like my router, a PiHole, access point etc.